# how to reformat a json in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I am trying to make a json file as I am new in python 
the json file
i have is as followed and i want to reformat it

```
{  
   "A1":"a1",
   "aback":"\u0259b\u00e6k",
   "abaft":"abaft",
   "abandon":"\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259n",
   "abandoned":"\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nd",
   "abandonment":"\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nm\u0259nt",
   "abase":"abase",
   "abash":"\u0259b\u00e6\u0283",
   "abashment":"abashment",
   "abate":"\u0259bet",
   "abatement":"\u0259betm\u0259nt",
   "abbey":"\u00e6bi",
   "abbreviate":"\u0259briviet",
   "abbreviation":"\u0259brivie\u0283\u0259n"
}
```

the format that i want to achieve is

```
{  
   word: "A1",
   transcription:"a1"
}
{
   word: "aback",
   transcription :"\u0259b\u00e6k"
}
{
  word:"abaft"
  transcrition:"abaft"
}
{
  word:"abbreviation",
  transcription:"\u0259brivie\u0283\u0259n"
}
```

Comment: The expected format is not valid json. What do you want it to be? A dictionary? Or a json? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to retain alphabetical order? FWIW, your input format is more useful than your output format because dictionary lookup is O(1) but list lookup is O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this code to a file such as `convert.py`

```
import sys
import json
from pprint import PrettyPrinter, pprint


def main():
    fn =   sys.argv[1]
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    for k, v in data.items():
        pprint({'word':k, 'transcription':v})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then run command `python convert.py YOUR_JSON_FILE_NAME`, enjoy it ~

Answer (score 2):

Read the JSON from the file and convert it to a dictionary. Use a list comprehension to generate a list of dictionaries and write that out as a JSON list:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as infile, open('out.json', 'w') as outfile:
    d = json.load(infile)
    json.dump([{'word': k, 'transcription': d[k]} for k in d], outfile)
```

For your input file this will produce an output file containing:

```
[{"transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6\u0283", "word": "abash"}, {"transcription": "\u0259briviet", "word": "abbreviate"}, {"transcription": "abaft", "word": "abaft"}, {"transcription": "a1", "word": "A1"}, {"transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nd", "word": "abandoned"}, {"transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nm\u0259nt", "word": "abandonment"}, {"transcription": "\u0259betm\u0259nt", "word": "abatement"}, {"transcription": "\u0259bet", "word": "abate"}, {"transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259n", "word": "abandon"}, {"transcription": "\u00e6bi", "word": "abbey"}, {"transcription": "\u0259brivie\u0283\u0259n", "word": "abbreviation"}, {"transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6k", "word": "aback"}, {"transcription": "abase", "word": "abase"}, {"transcription": "abashment", "word": "abashment"}]
```

You can format the output a bit, use `indent`:

```
json.dump([{'word': k, 'transcription': d[k]} for k in d], outfile, indent='')
```

will output:

```
[
    {
        "word": "aback",
        "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6k"
    },
    {
        "word": "abandonment",
        "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nm\u0259nt"
    },
    {
        "word": "abatement",
        "transcription": "\u0259betm\u0259nt"
    },
    {
        "word": "abbey",
        "transcription": "\u00e6bi"
    },
    {
        "word": "abbreviation",
        "transcription": "\u0259brivie\u0283\u0259n"
    },
    {
        "word": "abandoned",
        "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nd"
    },
    {
        "word": "abash",
        "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6\u0283"
    },
    {
        "word": "abaft",
        "transcription": "abaft"
    },
    {
        "word": "abashment",
        "transcription": "abashment"
    },
    {
        "word": "abate",
        "transcription": "\u0259bet"
    },
    {
        "word": "abbreviate",
        "transcription": "\u0259briviet"
    },
    {
        "word": "A1",
        "transcription": "a1"
    },
    {
        "word": "abandon",
        "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259n"
    },
    {
        "word": "abase",
        "transcription": "abase"
    }
]
```

Note that your requested format is not actually valid JSON. If you do not want the commas and list brackets you can write the file out like this:

```
with open('file.json') as infile, open('out.json', 'w') as outfile:
    d = json.load(infile)
    print(*[json.dumps({'word': k, 'transcription': d[k]}, indent='    ') for k in d], file=outfile, sep='\n')
```

```
{
    "word": "aback",
    "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6k"
}
{
    "word": "abandonment",
    "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nm\u0259nt"
}
{
    "word": "abatement",
    "transcription": "\u0259betm\u0259nt"
}
{
    "word": "abbey",
    "transcription": "\u00e6bi"
}
{
    "word": "abbreviation",
    "transcription": "\u0259brivie\u0283\u0259n"
}
{
    "word": "abandoned",
    "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259nd"
}
{
    "word": "abash",
    "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6\u0283"
}
{
    "word": "abaft",
    "transcription": "abaft"
}
{
    "word": "abashment",
    "transcription": "abashment"
}
{
    "word": "abate",
    "transcription": "\u0259bet"
}
{
    "word": "abbreviate",
    "transcription": "\u0259briviet"
}
{
    "word": "A1",
    "transcription": "a1"
}
{
    "word": "abandon",
    "transcription": "\u0259b\u00e6nd\u0259n"
}
{
    "word": "abase",
    "transcription": "abase"
}
```

Finally, if the order is important you can iterate over the sorted keys, just use:

`for k in sorted(d)`

where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [16]: d
Out[16]: {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}

In [17]: lis = []

In [18]: lis
Out[18]: []

In [19]: for key in d:
    ...:     dd ={}
    ...:     dd["word"] = key
    ...:     dd["transcrition"] = d[key]
    ...:     lis.append(dd)
    ...:     

In [20]: lis
Out[20]: 
[{'transcrition': 'A', 'word': 'a'},
 {'transcrition': 'C', 'word': 'c'},
 {'transcrition': 'B', 'word': 'b'}]
```